# Does the VS2012 SDK Include the VSIX Project Template?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vsix, visual-studio-sdk

I installed the VS2012 RC SDK but am not seeing a VSIX Project Template when creating a new project.  Am I missing something or is that template in a different SDK or something?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Do you have ".NET Framework 4.5" selected in the target framework dropdown?

Comment: That's a good question.  I'll check when I get home.

Comment: I was using the .NET Framework 4.5.  Added screenshot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok so this is a bit confusing but the **correct** place to locate the VSIX Project Template is here:

[image]

Comment: Sigh. I thought I had, but I actually installed the 2010 version. Oops.

Comment: After I installed that SDK there is nothing added at all

Comment: I find it best to use the "search" feature in the upper right corner. That will search all categories and is helpful when looking for a template that is hard to find.

Answer (score 4):

Downloading the Visual Studio 2012 SDK fixed it for me, the VSIX template is no longer missing under C#

You can get the SDK here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30668

Also be sure you select ".NET Framework 4.5" from the dropdown menu when looking under C#/VB.NET > Extensibility for the VSIX template, or you wont see it. I learned that thanks to this post:

[VSIX project template does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356572/vsix-project-template-does-not-exist)